# Assessing methods or properties from a Class

Tags: ios

I can't google the answer to this question maybe because I don't know the right term to use for search.

I have a class Class A and within Class A I create an instance of Class B. Class A and B is not the parent child relationship. I need to call some methods from Class A when something happens to Class B. How can this b done?

A simple example to visualise this could be I have a Class A inherited from UIView and created a Button_B to the UIView. If I tap the button, I need a method_C from Class A to be called.

Something like:

```
[parent.ButtonB method_C]
```

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Search **delegation in Objective c**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use protocol for achieving this. use this [link](http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Key Value Observing (described at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html) or NSNotificationCenter (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways for your approach.
Few are:_

1. Using Protocol / Delegate (Handling the responsibility of one class's object by another class's object).
2. NSNotificationCenter (Notify the user when something happens in your app, like application entered in background and pass the value)
3. Using KVO (Key Value Observer)
4. Similar , WillChangeValueforkey and DidChangeValueforKey

Cheers
Sanjay